# Add script to inside of vue template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need insert script like this

```
    <div data-player-id="912d05c">
  <script src="//cdn.flowplayer.com/players/7/flowplayer.async.js">
    { 
            "src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/69693f173770c49cbb5.mp4"
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

to inside of html under the vue.

So I found that I need to generate `script` tag by js but I'm not sure how to add

```
{ 
        "src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/69693f173770c49cbb5.mp4"
}
```

to this `script` tag

Code what I have (simplified):

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="videocontent"></div>
</div>

el: "#app",
data: {},
created: function() {
    let playerContainer = document.createElement('div');
    playerContainer.setAttribute('data-player-id','912d05c');
    let flowplayerScript = document.createElement('script');
    flowplayerScript.setAttribute('src', '//cdn.flowplayer.com/players/7/flowplayer.async.js');
    flowplayerScript.innerText = {"src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/productionadgate_video/eceae5886caaf69693f173770c49cbb5.mp4"};

    playerContainer.append(flowplayerScript);
    let container = document.getElementById('videocontent');
    container.append(playerContainer);
}
```

and `flowplayerScript.innerText = {"src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/productionadgate_video/eceae5886caaf69693f173770c49cbb5.mp4"};` is not correclty injected and player is always loading but not showing videos.  Also I was tried tu use:

```
flowplayerScript.onload = function(){
     return {
         "src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/productionadgate_video/eceae5886caaf69693f173770c49cbb5.mp4"
        }
};
```

but still not working :( and I'm getting the error like:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 0 flowplayer.async.js:2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure JavaScript installation, then init flowplayer in 'mounted' method.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      // select the above element as player container
      let containerEl = document.getElementById("videocontent")

      // install flowplayer into selected container
      flowplayer(containerEl, {
        clip: {
          sources: [
            { type: "application/x-mpegurl",
              src:  "//mydomain.com/video.m3u8" },
            { type: "video/mp4",
              src:  "//mydomain.com/video.mp4" }
          ]
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5b0cqp4g/)

Comment: well, I had such flowplayer initialization logic before, but there was the issue with adv videos, and after I contact flowplayer team and they tell me to use such a code....